# custom child components in angularjs2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I currently developing angular2 application . I would like to know how to add html attributes to custom components.

For example  lets assume i have custom dropdown component and am re-using in same page on many places. If i would like to develop some dropdowns as multiselect and some of them single select, Could you please tell me how to that. If I add mutiple on component template it is showing multiselect for all dropdowns. If I add to each component individually where am using, it is not understanding that "Multiple" attribute.

Comment: Plase, add the code you have tried so far?

Comment: <dropdown  multiple ></dropdown>,    I have created "dropdown " custom component , Could you help me how to add HTML "multiple" attribute to custom component.    Like how we use for regular html dropdown as below :                                                                       
     <select multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i would like to develop some dropdowns as multiselect and some of
>   them single select, Could you please tell me how to that.

You should be using a boolean `@Input` decorator defined in your custom component  (Question seems unclear and i am assuming that you didn't ask for an implementation logic of multi select and single select). Below gives an example of adding a `multiselect` check for your custom component and how parent should bind value to that attribute when rendering the custom component

In your custom component.ts class

```
 @Input() multiple: boolean = false;
```

In your custom html class

```
<div *ngIf="!multiple"> 
// render your single select html
</div>

<div *ngIf="multiple"> 
//render your multiple select html
</div>
```

In the parent html while rendering the custom component (assumpe **selector** as the name of the component)

```
// for multi select
<selector [multiple]=true> </select>
// for single select
<selector [multipl]=false> </select>
```

If your struggling to make a generic component supporting both single and multi select check this open source component [ng-select](https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select)

If you have no idea on `@Input` and `@Output` decorators in angular2 check this [article](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example)